# How to clone .git from GitHub to Google Drive with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, github-api

I am coding a Google Apps Script to backup all my GitHub repositories to Google Drive frequently.

For the JSON responses, it works fine.

For the .git archive itself I do not find any solution.

My goal is to get the .git archive with all branches included.

My last try:

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://' + accessToken + ':x-oauth-basic@github.com/' + repoFullName + '.git');
const content = response.getContentText();
DriveApp.createFile('Repository.git', content);
```

Resulting in a downloaded HTML page "page not found" by GitHub :-(

And:

```
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://github.com/' + repo.full_name + '/zipball/master/', { headers: { Authorization: 'token ' + accessToken } });
const content = response.getContent();
DriveApp.createFile('Repository.zip', content);
```

Resulting in a archive which macOS cannot read.

Any idea?

Best Regards,

Dennis

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? About your goal, for example, how about this flow? 1. Retrieve the repository list. 2. Download all repositories from the list as the zip files. 3. When the total size of all files is less than 50 MB, the file can be zipped by Google Apps Script. When the total size is over 50 MB, the files cannot be zipped by Google Apps Script. This is the specification of Google side. In this case, it supposes that your access token can be used. If this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: The simplest way to truly back up a git repo is to clone it, with git. If you are worried about GitHub losing your data, you can likely set up mirrors on another hosted git platform, such as GitLab, BitBucket, Azure DevOps, or host your own git server elsewhere. Then your backup is as easy as running `git fetch --all` for each repo (where the mirrors' lists of remotes can each include the origin repo on GitHub and any other mirrors you've made).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your ideas. My goal is to backup all issues, comments, files etc.

I solved my issue to download the master branch as zip file as follows:

```
const gitFileResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch('http://github.com/' + repo.full_name + '/zipball/master/', { headers: { Authorization: 'token ' + accessToken } })
const gitFileContent = gitFileResponse.getBlob()
gitFileContent.setContentTypeFromExtension() 
DriveApp.createFile(gitFileContent).setName('Master.zip')
```

:-)